# What is the => token called?

Tags: syntax, c#-3.0, lambda

The => token is part of the C# 3.0 lambda syntax. My efforts to find the name of this token have failed so far.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx Refers to it as the "lambda operator" which is often read as "goes to"

Comment: Rubyists might call it the "broken space ship operator" :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pronounce "=>" as used in lambda expressions in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022/how-do-i-pronounce-as-used-in-lambda-expressions-in-net)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx)

Comment: Yes, I should have found this fairly easily myself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx

Comment: Also known as the "wang" operator.

Answer (score 7):

What it is called, in terms of how to pronounce it when reading code, is covered by Eric Lippert in [Reading Code Over the Telephone](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/16/reading-code-over-the-telephone.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. This has been bugging me since it came out. I can't say it so it is harder for me to grok it.

Answer (score 6):

It's referred to as the 'goes to' operator.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879860/what-is-the-token-called/879924#879924) depends on the context:

```
c=>c+1
```

*c **goes to** c plus one*

```
(Customer c)=>c.Name
```

*customer c **becomes** c dot name*

```
(Customer c)=>c.Age > 21
```

*customer c **such that** c dot age is greater than 21*

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Taken from the above:
All lambda expressions use the lambda operator =>, which is read as "goes to".