# What is the name of this operator =>?

Tags: c#, nomenclature

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the => token called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879860/what-is-the-token-called)

What is the name of this operator in C#?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's referred to as the [lambda operator in the MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

> All lambda expressions use the lambda
>   operator =>, which is read as "goes
>   to". The left side of the lambda
>   operator specifies the input
>   parameters (if any) and the right side
>   holds the expression or statement
>   block. The lambda expression x => x *
>   x is read "x goes to x times x." This
>   expression can be assigned to a
>   delegate type as follows:

Answer (score 3):

Is the [lambda operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx).

As a side note, in Ruby is known as the 'hashrocket' operator.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking in the context of LINQ that is a [lamdba operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Such as ...

```
var selectedValues = myList.Where(v=>v.Name="Matt");
```

You can use these in your own methods in place of delgates.  Possible uses would include something like this...

```
void DoWork<T>(T input, Func<T, bool> doAction, Action<T> action)
{
    if (doAction(input))
        action(input);
}
```

... usage of the above method would look like ...

```
DoWork(5, i=>i>1, v=>Console.WriteLine(v));
```

... because 5 is greater than 1 this would display 5 on the console.

Comment: Lambda operators aren't only used with LINQ.

Comment: I do beleive my example shows that... I said in the context of becasue he could have seen something nuts in an example like `for (; i=>1;)` and may not realize that is a normal expression. The even more fun thing is in LINQ you could also do `.Select(i=>"New Value")` to create an enumerable set of "New Value" the length of the input set.

Comment: Just to be clear, `=>` isn't "the lambda expression" - it is *part* of it.

Comment: I assumed that was clear... but I will change my answer.

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, to Rubyists, this operator is called the "hash rocket". (There's even a [company with that name](http://www.hashrocket.com/).)