# The name of the => operator in C#

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the => token called?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/879860/what-is-the-token-called)

Hey,

In LINQ what is the name of the => operator e.g:

```
list.Where(a => a.value == 5);
```

Comment: Operators as such are hard to search for, but the combination '<language> operators' pretty quickly leads to the desired information usually.

Comment: On a side note are you familiar with the **-->** operator: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Comment: @Shiftbit Snark hunting, are we?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's called the lambda operator and is pronounced "goes to".

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx).

Comment: +1 just for beating skeet by 5 seconds :) There should be badge for that

Comment: @Dennis Trust me. I was shocked when I hit Save and Jon's answer appeared. However, I think he beat me by 4 seconds. (_I_ had to go look it up. Jon _knew_ it.)

Comment: @Dennis: Um, I think I beat Michael. At least, my answer has the lower post ID :)

Comment: "Goes to"?  That's silly, goes to what? The variable isn't going anywhere.  If for some reason I was averse to just saying "a in lambda" I would probably use "for...in expression..." as in "for a in the expression a dot value equals 5".  I guess "goes to" is shorter though. :P

Comment: @CodexArcanum: "Goes to" is a pretty frequently used way of pronouncing it. I tend to depend on the context though. "Goes to" is fine for a projection, but doesn't work as well in a predicate.

Answer (score 8):

It's the lambda operator. Or at least, an expression of the form

```
x => y
```

(or any of the longer forms involving `=>`) is a [*lambda expression*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx). (I don't personally tend to think of it as an operator as such, even though the linked page refers to the lambda operator. The C# 4 spec doesn't contain the phrase "lambda operator" anywhere.)

Comment: @Chaos, did you mean +1 for *being* Jon Skeet?

Comment: @adrift: No, Jon Skeet and only Jon Skeet can beat Jon Skeet.

Comment: haha, just out of curiosity, how did Jon Skeet become the Chuck Norris of SO? (this is definitely not a complaint btw)

Answer (score 2):

The lambda operator.

Answer (score 1):

You read it as "such that". So your example reads as "list where a such that a dot value equals 5"

Answer (score 0):

its called ... lambda

Answer (score 0):

Its used to create delegates or expression tree types, and yes the new term for it is lambda expression