# Is there a C#-like lambda syntax in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a framework or post processor for JavaScript that supports lambda syntax like in C#?

Function definitions in CoffeeScript seem to look like lambdas but I have not looked into them thoroughly.

Can anyone tell me, *can I use lambda syntax in JavaScript?*

Comment: What do you mean ? Javascript has built-in lambdas.

Comment: working on it!
https://github.com/elmerbulthuis/sjs

Comment: Yes, there are "lambda expressions" in JavaScript but they are called **arrow function expression**. [See this link for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: this is funny cos actually lambdas in c# and now Java have been actually inspired from javascript, not the other way around

Comment: @slaphappy did you mean [function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function) when you said vanilla JavaScript has built-in lambdas? You use function expressions as lambda expression or something else.

Answer (score 74):

Lambda functions with similar syntax are included in [ECMAscript 6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions), they're known as "arrow functions". An example:

`["duck", "cat", "goat"].filter(el => el.length > 3);` returns `["duck", "goat"]`

There's currently support in recent versions of [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) and [Chrome](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5047308127305728).

To use this syntax in JavaScript that's targeting older browsers there are tools that can compile ES 6 to a more widely supported version - for example the tools [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler).

Comment: I believe one can use Traceur to run it in any browser. https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: @stimpy77, Link is broken, should be: https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: If actually 'nothing' I think it would valuable if you explain why you think so. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's worth adding that you can use code blocks: array.filter(el => {console.log(el); return el.length>3;});

Answer (score 11):

You could use typescript ([www.typescriptlang.org/)](http://www.typescriptlang.org):

```
function (d, i) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
}
```

would become

```
(d, i) =>  "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
```

and much more cool stuff, like typing: ... that's if you are into that

Comment: This is now in Firefox nightly too, so seems a legit suggestion - http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-13.2

Comment: The link is now http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-arrow-function-definitions

Comment: +1: I have been looking everywhere for info on `()=>{}` etc in Javascript... I did not realise it was just a Typescript extension I had accidentally tripped over. Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 5):

I started creating an extender for jQuery which does exactly the thing you are asking. 
[JS-Lambda](https://github.com/Ruben-J/JS-Lambda)

For example in C#:

```
  coll.TakeWhile(x => x.index < 3);
```

Looks like:

```
 $(coll).TakeWhile("x => x.index < 3");
```

Comment: I know the lib isn't a fully functioning lib and i will never use it in a project, but it was just a fun hour project to get a lambda expression working in JavaScript.

Comment: Although it doesn't, without ES6 support, give you the lambda stuff, lodash or underscore are probably more complete/stable versions of what your library is trying to achieve.  Might be worth taking inspiration from, at least.

Answer (score 3):

Javascript has very nice anonymous functions that allows you to create lambdas anyWhere you need as a function but the implementation comes with some much words and scope creation repeating:

```
function(name){
     return "Hello, " + name;
}
```

Thanks to EcmaScript 2015 lambda expresion is now available for javaScript with simpler syntax as [Arrow Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

```
(name) => "Hello, " + name
```

Answer (score 3):

**FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/vktawbzg/

**NPM:** https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqscript

**GITHUB:** https://github.com/sevensc/linqscript

using Typescript i created a class `List<T>` which extends `Array<T>`

usage:

```
var list = new List<ListView>();
...
var selected = list.Items.Where(x => x.Selected);
```

implementation:

```
 export class List<T> extends Array<T> {

    public Where(callback: (value: T) => boolean, thisArg?: any): List<T> {
            try {
                const list = new List<T>();

                if (this.length <= 0)
                    return list;

                if (typeof callback !== "function")
                    throw new TypeError(callback + ' is not a function');

                for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
                    const c = this[i];
                    if (c === null)
                        continue;

                    if (callback.call(thisArg, c))
                        list.Add(c);
                }

                return list;
            }
            catch (ex) {
                return new List<T>();
            }
        }
...
}
```

**EDIT:** 
I created a github repo:
https://github.com/sevensc/linqscript

Comment: Hi I'm trying to make the same, and specifically targetting the GroupBy method. do you have a link or any good resources?

Comment: Hi, yes of course, take a look at my github repo: https://github.com/sevensc/linqscript for some inspiration.

Answer (score 3):

Exact Matthew Mcveigh!!

I want to contribute too, see this example

```js
"use strict";
/* Lambda Helper to print  */
function PrintLineForElement(element, index, array){
  document.write("a[" + index + "] = " + JSON.stringify(element)+"<br>");
}
/* function to print array */
function Print(a){
   a.forEach(PrintLineForElement)
   document.write("<br>");
}
/* user model */
class User{
  constructor(_id,_name,_age,_job){
    this.id = _id;
       this.name = _name;
    this.age = _age;
       this.job = _job;
  }
} 
/* Provaider users */
class UserService{ 

  constructor(){ } 
    
  GetUsers(){
        //fake ajax response
    let data = []; 
        data.push(new User(1,"Juan",20,"AM"));
        data.push(new User(2,"Antonio",20,"AM"));
        data.push(new User(3,"Miguel Angel",30,"Developer"));
        data.push(new User(4,"Bea",26,"AM"));
        data.push(new User(5,"David",24,"Developer")); 
        data.push(new User(6,"Angel",24,"Developer")); 
        data.push(new User(7,"David",34,"TeamLead"));
        data.push(new User(8,"Robert",35,"TeamLead"));
        data.push(new User(9,"Carlos",35,"TeamLead"));   
    
        return data;
  }
}

const userService = new UserService();
const users =  userService.GetUsers();

//get user order by name
document.write("All users </br>");
Print(users);

//get user order by name
document.write("Order users by name ASC : users.sort((a,b)=>{return a.name > b.name })</br>");
Print(users.sort((a,b)=>{return a.name > b.name; }));
document.write("Order users by name DESC : users.sort((a,b)=>{return a.name < b.name })</br>");
Print(users.sort((a,b)=>{return a.name < b.name; }));

//get user filter by age 
document.write("Only users oldest or equal than 25 : users.filter( (w) => {return w.age >= 25;} )</br>");
Print(users.filter( (w) => {return w.age >= 25;} )); 
document.write("Only users smallest or equal than 25 : users.filter( (w) => {return w.age <= 25;} )</br>");
Print(users.filter( (w) => {return w.age <= 25;} )); 

//GroupBY 
/**
* custom group by with Array.prototype.keys
**/

Array.prototype.groupBy = function(f)
{
  let groups = [];
  this.forEach( function( o )
  {
    let group =  f(o) ;
    groups[group] = groups[group] || [];
    groups[group].push( o );  
  });

  return Object.keys(groups).map( function( group )
  {
    return groups[group]; 
  })
}

document.write("Group user by age </br>");
Print(users.groupBy( (w) => {return w.age } )); 

document.write("Group user by job </br>");
Print(users.groupBy( (w) => {return w.job } )); 

document.write("Group user by job</br>");
Print(users.groupBy( (g) => {return [g.job] } ));

document.write("Group user by job and age then order by name </br>");
Print(users.sort((a,b)=>{return a.job > b.job}).groupBy( (g) => {return [g.job+g.age] } ));

document.write("Group user by job and age then order by name and filter where age < 25 and job equal AM </br>");
Print(users.sort((a,b)=>{return a.job > b.job}).filter((w)=>{ return w.age<25 || w.job == "AM" }).groupBy( (g) => {return [g.job+g.age] } ));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/angelfragap/0b5epjw3/29/