# Filter Illustrator page items by property in Javascript

Tags: javascript, adobe-illustrator

I am trying to manipulate certain page items in an Illustrator document that has 30,000 page items. I am trying to avoid looping through each one. What is the Javascript equivalent to this AppleScript?

```
set xxx to every page item whose note = "John"
```

An example of the note value for the first page item would be:

```
set xxx to (do javascript "app.activeDocument.pathItems[0].note")
```

Ultimately, I just need the count (length) of the array.

After a quick look at a tutorial, I pieced this together for Javascript example. Is this the only way of getting the result?

```
docRef = app.activeDocument;

var pathLength = docRef.pathItems.length;

var hitList = []
for (i = 0; i<pathLength; i++)

{
if (docRef.pathItems[i].note= "John")
{
 hitList.push(i)   
}
}

alert(hitList.length)
```

Comment: What kind of looping are you trying to avoid? Clearly there has to be a loop somewhere!

Comment: As you can tell, I am not familiar with Javascript. The AppleScript command I posted in my question accomplishes the task without (explicitly) looping through each item to test the value of the properties. Is there a javascript equivalent for searching an array of objects for a specific property without going into a loop?

Comment: No, JS has no implicit loop as AppleScript apparently does. Is there any reason you're trying to avoid a `for` loop? It's only 3 characters.

Comment: Ha. I am concerned about the time it will take to check the properties of 30,000 items individually.

Comment: There's no way to avoid checking all those properties. Either AppleScript loops through them or JavaScript does.

Answer (score -1):

There is a technique called Lambda expressions which could work for you. The type of Lambda expression you would be looking for would be Lambdas with Standard Query Operations. Essentially what you would do is pull back a list of items where docRef.pathItems[i].note= "John"

The first link will give you a better understanding of what Lambda expressions are in C#
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

The second link will point you in the direction of where you can find a Javascript lambda expression builder much like C#
[Is there a C#-like lambda syntax in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190439/is-there-a-c-like-lambda-syntax-in-javascript)