# The => lamba operator (used when linq querying)

Tags: c#, .net

Can someone explain this to me in simple and terms and give me an example if possible? I've looked around but no one seems to explain the operator properly that I can actually understand it.

EDIT: I see it a lot in MVC apps, which is why I want to understand it

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/lambda it explains very nicely. Go ahead and read it. There are examples too.

Comment: If you have a specific question that the duplicates don't cover then come back with a new question.

Comment: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167343/c-sharp-lambda-expressions-why-should-i-use-them) that may be of interest to you

Comment: What part of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb397687.aspx do you have problems understanding? That contains examples and explains it in fairly precise technical terms well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022/how-do-i-pronounce-as-used-in-lambda-expressions-in-net <-- I like the pronounciation of the lambda as "such that".

Answer (score -3):

It's simply the syntax the compiler uses to treat a bit of plain text as a lambda expression. There's no hidden magic behind it.