# What's the name of the "=>" operator in linq (e.g .Select(x=>x.Prop1) )

Tags: javascript, c#, operator-keyword

What's the name of the "=>" operator  (e.g in C# linq .Select(x=>x.Prop1) )

It might not even be an operator.

Does it have a different name in different languages (C# vs JavaScript)

*Tagging as operator / C# / javascript - Not sure where this fits in...*

Comment: It's a "lambda operator" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/bb311046.aspx In JS it's an "arrow function operator"

Comment: And it's pronounced "goes into" e.g. "x goes into x dot prop1"

Comment: @JohnWu: I don't think I've ever heard of it as "goes into" - but "goes to" instead. (Or just "to", e.g. "x to x dot prop1".

Comment: The things you learn on SO!  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022/how-do-i-pronounce-as-used-in-lambda-expressions-in-net)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# it's called a "lambda operator". In JS it's called an "arrow function operator".

References:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/bb311046.aspx
- http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-arrow-function-definitions

Comment: Yup, it's like the JavaScript guys didn't know the proper name of the operator.

Comment: @IllidanS4 unless there is no single proper name for it.

Answer (score 1):

The `=>` [shorthand](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) declaration of a function in javascript.

Example usage would be:

```
addition:(x,y)=>{
   return x+y
}
```

Comment: It's a bit more than shorthand, considering its effect on scope...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan definitely. I added that link to the mdn article so he can read more in detail.

Comment: Is the lodash one where you do .map(x => x.id) also the same (a function declaration) or do they 'overload' it?

Answer (score 1):

It's sometimes called a "fat arrow" (or "big boned arrow") but most often called a "lambda"

Comment: `=>` is called a "fat arrow" in PHP but not in C#. Nevertheless, I  found that .NET people also understand that name since it's kind of a descriptive term.