# How do I read the following arrow function

Tags: javascript

How can I read the following arrow function in English?  I can understand that there are 2 parameters namely dispatch and getState.  How do I read the remaining part?

How to write it as a normal function?

```
    const apiMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {
```

Comment: There's actually only one parameter in every function there - the `apiMiddleware` function accepts *one* parameter, an object with two properties, `dispatch` and `getState`. It then returns a function that takes in a `next` parameter and returns *another* function, which takes an *action* parameter.

Comment: Depends on how it is constructed. I found that usually it reads "goes to", but you can check also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274022/how-do-i-pronounce-as-used-in-lambda-expressions-in-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Written as a normal function, the declaration will look like this:

```
const apiMiddleware = function({ dispatch, getState}){
 return function(next) {
    return function(action) {
      return something;
  }
 }
}
```

I suggest you to read this great article about higher order arrow functions [here](https://developer.ibm.com/node/2016/01/11/higher-order-functions-in-es6easy-as-a-b-c/)

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find this response useful.

```
let squarevalue = input => { input * input }

let multiplyvalue = (input, multiplier) => { input * multiplier }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what it might look like if it were written in es5 syntax

```js
var apiMiddleware = function apiMiddleware(_ref) {
  var dispatch = _ref.dispatch;
  var getState = _ref.getState;
  return function (next) {
    return function (action) {
      console.log('action function body');
    };
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Writing this:

```
const apiMiddleware = ({ dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {
```

As a normal function (by normal I mean no arrows):

```
const apiMiddleware = function({dispatch, getState}) {
    return function(next) {
        return function(action) {
            //Rest of the code
        }
    }
}
```

And here's how you'd write it in ES5:

```
var apiMiddleware = function(data) {
    var dispatch = data.dispatch;
    var getState = data.getState;
    return function(next) {
        return function(action) {
            //Rest of the code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the ES6 nice features called [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring). This one is also interesting and may be related to your code in question:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators#Iterators

Try pasting the code into this and see the transformed script as vanilla JS: https://es6console.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following babel compiler to convert the es6 code into es5 -

[babel compiler](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhgBwJYFkkBN0BsCmB3OAJxxgF4YAKAbxnSQgTimAAsAaGAcxygGUomOAL4BKMgD4YYHAA9YpSXGBQk4CTBowhQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=)